# Setting the scaleHeight attribute of an xterm while within the xterm

Tags: command-line, xterm

Because my underscores keep disappearing in my xterm's I've set

```
XTerm.scaleHeight:          1.1
```

In my .Xresources file.

This fixes the problem, but when I switch between different external monitors, the `scaleHeight` setting seems to get lost or returned to it's default value, or something.

I can recover my custom setting by rebooting but obviously I don't want to do that all the time.    So I'm hoping that when I lose it I may be able to reset it from the command line within an xterm.    I downloaded `xtermcontrol` which seemed promising, but the man page doesn't instruct how to set an obscure attribute like `scaleHeight`.       Can anybody advise if it's possible please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `xterm` can modify this value runtime.

You can place your setting in `~/XTerm` in which case it's read every time `xterm` starts up. After modifying this file, all you need is quit and restart `xterm`.

If you place it in `~/.Xresources`, you need to execute `xrdb merge ~/.Xresources` and then restart `xterm` for the changes to take effect.

This is because `xterm` itself looks at the contents of `~/XTerm`; and queries the X server for the server-side resources which are loaded to the X server at startup or manually using `xrdb`.

No need to reboot the system. (Worst case you could just log out of the graphical environment and log back again, but that's not needed either.)